# I confront an issue when I read head.s (one of Linux kernel files)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The code fragment in `head.s` looks like this:

```
movl $swapper_pg_dir-0xc0000000,%eax
movl %eax,%cr3 /* set the page table pointer.. */
movl %cr0,%eax
orl $0x80000000,%eax
movl %eax,%cr0 /* ..and set paging (PG) bit */
```

Before the kernel enables the paging mechanism (of course, the PE flag now has already been enabled), it loads the address of temporary Page Directory Table into `%cr3`.

The issue is:
I think the kernel should directly put the `$swapper_pg_dir` value into `%eax` instead of `$swapper_pg_dir-0xc0000000`. I am aware that I am wrong, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel sees memory as if based at 0xC0000000. Any memory allocation, pointer or global, is located between 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF.
However, for HW controllers, such as the MMU or any co processor, memory window is porbably based at 0x00000000.

So, when loading a pointer to a table or descriptor to a HW engine, it must be based at 0x00000000

Comment: Hi, @adashi , I am sorry,I am a rookie to Linux kernel, so I cannot comprehend your reply. Could you detail it?   I think $swapper_pg_dir - 0xc0000000 is not the positive integer,I want to know why we don't load the   $swapper_pg_dir into %eax, $swapper_pg_dir is the physical address, isn't it?

Comment: No. When building the Linux kernel, the linker assigns addresses in "kernel space" (virtual addresses in the range used by the kernel) to all kernel symbols. So `$swapper_pg_dir` will evaluate to a virtual address, which is only usable AFTER the page tables are set up. `$swapper_pg_dir-0xc0000000` is the corresponding physical address.

Comment: As Alex noted, kernel is linked to address 0xc0000000. Each process in user-space has it's own virtual memory map, so multiple processes see different memory page when pointing to the same address (1MB for example). However, when executing kernel code (for example when calling a system call), all processes execute it in the same virtual (but linear) address space - starting at 0xc0000000.

0xc0000000 is historical and relies on variables such as 32bit address space, memory holes in PC systems and sizes of system memory, acceptable back then.

http://bottomupcs.sourceforge.net/csbu/x2816.htm

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks why Linux minus `0xc0000000` from `swapper_pg_dir`. The reason for this math is that `%cr3` needs physical address while `$swapper_pg_dir` is a virtual address. In the initial phase of kernel page initialization, there are two mappings for 8MB RAM (`0 to 0x007fffff`). First mapping is `one to one` for virtual addresses `0x00000000-0x007fffff` while other is for `0xc0000000-0xcoo7fffff`. In order to get physical address of `swapper_pg_dir`, we have to subtract `0xc0000000` from address of `swapper_pg_dir`.